# Trying to understand the BroadcastReceiver in android coding

Tags: java, android, android-intent

First off am a complete newbie to Android coding and the logic is really confusion me. Originally im Flash developer and im familiar with concepts from there, while Android is complete set of new concepts. For example (correct me if im wrong) a Intent is like an Event and BroadcastReceiver is a EventListener ?

Well it is here im stuck, if it is so, Intent is Event and broadcastReceiver is eventListener then my question is how do i assign a variable, data that ive handeled in onReceive method ?

Ive been searching for long time now and really get angry at myself for not understanding the logic. Im trying to compare and associate things to ActionScript3 and Javascript (some stuff in JS is pretty close to AS3).

Now to the code im trying to write and the problem i got.

Im trying to get myself into writing a Android Native Extension for Adobe AIR...
So, far so good at least in some way :)

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.as3breeze.air"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BluetoothExtension"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As i see, the main activity is my BluetoothExtension.java which is following:
Notice it implements FREExtension (created by Adobe for Native Extensions)

```
package com.as3breeze.air;

import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREExtension;
import com.as3breeze.air.BluetoothExtensionContext;

public class BluetoothExtension implements FREExtension {

    protected BluetoothExtensionContext BEC;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public FREContext createContext(String arg0) {
        BEC = new BluetoothExtensionContext();
        return BEC;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BEC.dispose();
        BEC = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {}
}
```

Thats the Activity, right ?

And it creates Context which is following (am leaving out the @imports):

```
public class BluetoothExtensionContext  extends FREContext {

public BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
public Activity extensionActivity;
public FREArray nonBoundedDevices;

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Map<String, FREFunction> getFunctions() {

    Map<String, FREFunction> functionMap=new HashMap<String, FREFunction>();

    functionMap.put("initialize", new Initialize());

    // Leaving out some stuff here and listing only the important things...

    functionMap.put("listDevices", new ListAvailableDevices());

    return functionMap;


    }
}
```

Now, as you see above i got some public vars for easier access, those are initiated inside new Initialize() which looks like this:

```
package com.as3breeze.air;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;
import com.adobe.fre.FREWrongThreadException;
import com.as3breeze.air.BluetoothExtensionContext;

public class Initialize implements FREFunction {

    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

        BluetoothExtensionContext bluetoothContext = (BluetoothExtensionContext) context;
        bluetoothContext.bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothContext.extensionActivity = bluetoothContext.getActivity();

        FREObject returnData = null;
        if( bluetoothContext.bluetooth == null )
        {
            try {
                returnData = FREObject.newObject("notSupported");
            } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {}
        }
        return returnData;
    }
}
```

Initiation works fine, i also got other methods listed in the Map such as enabling / disabling bluetooth, discoverability and few more, everything there works well.

But the problem is in this one: functionMap.put("listDevices", new ListAvailableDevices());

The class is created and running and returning, it looks like this:

```
package com.as3breeze.air;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.adobe.fre.FREASErrorException;
import com.adobe.fre.FREArray;
import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREInvalidObjectException;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;
import com.adobe.fre.FRETypeMismatchException;
import com.adobe.fre.FREWrongThreadException;

public class ListAvailableDevices implements FREFunction {

    static FREArray returnDevicesArr = null;


    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
        BluetoothExtensionContext bluetoothContext = (BluetoothExtensionContext) context;
        returnDevicesArr = bluetoothContext.nonBoundedDevices;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                int index = 0;

                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice bt = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    Toast.makeText( context, "Searching devices...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FREArray deviceName;
                    try {
                        deviceName = FREArray.newArray(1);
                        deviceName.setObjectAt(0, FREObject.newObject(bt.getName()));
                        deviceName.setObjectAt(1, FREObject.newObject(bt.getAddress()));

                        returnDevicesArr.setObjectAt(index, deviceName);
                        index++;
                    } catch (FREASErrorException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FREInvalidObjectException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FRETypeMismatchException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        bluetoothContext.extensionActivity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        bluetoothContext.bluetooth.startDiscovery();
        return null; // Or to use return returnDeviceArr;

    }
}
```

As you see, im trying to store  all found devices in returnDeviceArr either to return from call() or in some "global" variable defined in BluetoothExtensionContext.java, it does not matter which way to go, i just need to get hold of that data.

Im not being able to reach the returnDeviceArr variable from onReceive method. Ive also tested to create a new FREArray inside onReceive and store devices data there, so it can be returned but return null; at bottom of call(){ ... } is fired and ultimately giving me null value.

So, how can i make it possible to replace that  return null with return returnDeviceArr; and get the array of available devices ?

Im hoping for code examples and explanations so i can start to understand Android coding without using visual components.

Answer (score 0):

The BlueToothExtension class must extend the activity class. Declaring in the manifest alone is not enough. And you should register your broadcast receiver with the intent. Check out the android development guide for more detail.

For Intents to pass variables, you should put them in extras like

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, target.class);

intent.putExtra("variable", value);

startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);`

In the target class you can fetch the variable using intent.getStringExtra("variable");

Comment: "must extend from activity class", does it mean it wont work in my case otherwise as Native extension for AIR ? Also, could you please give a code example, trust me ive gone thru the documentation, but since there is explanation on where (which classes) methods should be used, i feel a bit lost :/ If i were to use Intent and startactivityforresult, in which class i should add it to, BluetoothExtension which in that case should extend activity ? Thanks for your response, really lookign forward to get a grip of android coding :D

Comment: ahh one more thing i saw now that confuses me: Intent intent = new Intent(this, target.class); what is target.class, is it some other class or is that specifically referring to "this" ?

Comment: Make the class BluetoothExtension extend the class Activity like this public class BluetoothExtension extends Activity implements FREExtension {

Comment: The Target.class is the target class you want to call. If you have an activity that you want to fire up, you make it the 2nd parameter in the startActivity call.

Comment: actually found another solution that works for now, wait() just before return